# Calling a outside class method from Jar class

Tags: java

I have created a class "`Class B`"

```
package com.b

public class B
{
    public void printMsg()    
    {
        System.out.println("Called");
    }
}
```

I have created a jar file with below class "`Class A`"

```
package com.a

import com.b

public class A extends B
{

}
```

When i tried to load jar dynamically using below code, I am getting error "`Class B`" "`classnotfoundexception`"

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL(jarFullPath) });
Class<?> cla = cl.loadClass(className);
Object obj = cla.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is because you did not provide any parent `ClassLoader` to your `URLClassLoader` such that it can find `A` but not `B`, try this instead:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(
    new URL[] {new URL(jarFullPath)}, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
);
```

This use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` as parent `ClassLoader` corresponding to the context `ClassLoader`.